# Using "Run..." creates a different user.config

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, app-config

My application connects to different databases. The connection strings are saved in the user settings. I cannot use the application scope because the data is changed at run-time.

If the user starts the application normally there is no problem. However, if he uses the `"Run..."` command from the `Start` menu then a different folder in *`User\AppData\Local\MyApplication`* is created containing a different *`user.config`*.

Is there any way to stop or bypass this behavior?

Comment: This is normal, expected behaviour. You're running as a different user. That user gets their own user settings (the clue is kindof in the name)

Comment: When i view the processes in the Task Manager it shows the same owner no matter how i started it. I dont use _runas_ and the _user.config_ is created an the AppData folder of the same user, just with a different ID, i am confused how this can be another user.

Comment: Its not possible to stop this behavior. The only solution is to generate the missing configuration data when the application is started ( if it is missing ).  Any other way is a hack and not guaranteed to work in every case.

Comment: There's no way to stop this behavior, but for the exact same reason I don't use the Properties.Settings.Default and instead store my data in an XML file under `%LOCALAPPDATA%/MyCompanyName/MyApplicationName`, as then I can be sure it's the same data that I saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior cannot be avoided.

It seems that Windows does not identify programs started by other programs as the same as programs which are run by the user.

To solve the problem you have to avoid settings made by the ConfigurationManager and create your own files to save data as pointed out in the comments.